# Nested mappings are not allowed in compact mappings - Working on .yml for mcmmo

Tags: yaml, minecraft

I'm having trouble with adding modded items into my mcmmo plugin which usses .yml files to read those.

```
Boots:    
    Travelers Boots: tconstruct:travelers_boots
        Repairable: true
        Repair_Material: minecraft:copper_ingot
        Repair_Material_Data_Value: 0
        Repair_Material_Quantity: 1
        Repair_Material_Pretty_Name: Copper Ingot
        Repair_MinimumLevel: 80
        Repair_XpMultiplier: 1.0
        Durability: 130
    Plate Boots: tconstruct:plate_boots
        Repairable: true
        Repair_Material: tconstruct:cobalt_ingot
        Repair_Material_Data_Value: 0
        Repair_Material_Quantity: 1
        Repair_Material_Pretty_Name: Cobalt Ingot
        Repair_MinimumLevel: 150
        Repair_XpMultiplier: 1.2
        Durability: 390
    Slimeboots: tconstruct:slime_boots
        Repairable: true
        Repair_Material: minecraft:slime_ball
        Repair_Material_Data_Value: 0
        Repair_Material_Quantity: 5
        Repair_Material_Pretty_Name: Slimeball
        Repair_MinimumLevel: 250
        Repair_XpMultiplier: 1.5
        Durability: 546
    Chocodisguise Boots: chococraft:choco_disguise_boots
        Repairable: true
        Repair_Material: chococraft:chocobo_feather
        Repair_Material_Data_Value: 0
        Repair_Material_Quantity: 1
        Repair_Material_Pretty_Name: Chocobo Feather
        Repair_MinimumLevel: 75
        Repair_XpMultiplier: 1.0
        Durability: 2600
```

When starting up server it spams alot of "Nested mappings are not allowed in compact mappings in line x column y"

****I'm using Notepad++ for editing the file.

I tried changing the spaces at the start of the columns, checked my notpad++ program and put a check to the option of auto swapping tabs into spaces. (read in a forum that might help)

Ran it through YAMLlint the YAML validator and it says:

"Nested mappings are not allowed in compact mappings at line 2, column 22
Implicit keys need to be on a single line at line 2, column 22
Nested mappings are not allowed in compact mappings at line 3, column 21
Implicit keys need to be on a single line at line 3, column 21
Nested mappings are not allowed in compact mappings at line 4, column 26
Implicit keys need to be on a single line at line 4, column 26"

^Hope this will help troubleshooting!

Thank you for reading! I'm hoping someone can tell what the problem is.

Comment: This is not valid YAML. A mapping's key can only hold either another map (like `Boots` does), or a sequence (children starting with `-`, not used here), or a scalar value (like `Repairable` or `Repair_Material` etc. do). It cannot be more than just one of these at the same time. But `Travelers Boots` and `Plate Boots` etc. have scalar values (`tconstruct:travelers_boots`, `tconstruct:plate_boots`, etc.) **and** nested mappings (`Repairable`, `Repair_Material`) which is not possible at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. So would it be possible by sequencing them with - ? Would I have to put a - before every column or is what im intending to do simply not possible? Because these are basically in the format of the default.yml from mcmmo but somehow this simply isnt correct yaml.

Comment: The validity issue can be resolved in so many ways. But I don't know what you *really* want to represent with your document (and I don't know Minecraft so I can't come up with an educated guess either).